# Change set of indices

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I don't know the general case / words for the thing Im looking for, so here's rather an example. I create a matrix as

```
test = np.arange(0, 100, 1).reshape((5,5,-1))
idx = test > 50
```

now `test[idx]` will give me the values where `test > 50`. `idx` contains a set of elements that satisfy my condition. Say the indices of `idx` where `idx==TRUE` are (not actually true, just example)

```
(1,1,1)
(2,1,1)
(3,1,1)
(4,2,4)
```

Then I would like to create a new matrix, `idx2`, such that it has TRUE elements only on

```
(1,1,0)
(2,1,0)
(3,1,0)
(4,2,0)
```

That is, informally speaking , I am looking for

```
test > 50 & "switch axis=2 value from whatever it was to 0"
```

Perhaps someone who understands my request can rephrase the question, especially the title, and remove my fluff... thanks :)

#### 2d example

I unfortunately can't give the output if `idx2` in the 3d case, but in the less meaningful 2d case, here is how `idx` looks:

```
test = np.arange(0, 10, 1).reshape((5, -1), order='F')
idx = test > 5
idx
array([[False, False],
       [False,  True],
       [False,  True],
       [False,  True],
       [False,  True]], dtype=bool)
```

and now, `test > 5 and reset axis=1 to 0` would be:

```
idx2
array([[False, False],
       [True,  False],
       [True,  False],
       [True,  False],
       [True,  False]], dtype=bool)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
test=np.arange(0,100,1).reshape(5,5,-1)
idx=test>50
X,Y,Z=np.nonzero(idx)
```

These are your nonzero indices, in 3 arrays.
Now make a copy, but with `Z` being all 0s

```
idx1=np.zeros_like(idx)
idx1[X,Y,np.zeros_like(Z)]=True
```

`np.nonzero(idx)` produces

```
(array([2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3,
        3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4,
        4, 4, 4], dtype=int32),
 array([2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3,
        3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4,
        4, 4, 4], dtype=int32),
 array([3, 0, 1, 2, 3, 0, 1, 2, 3, 0, 1, 2, 3, 0, 1, 2, 3, 0, 1, 2, 3, 0, 1,
        2, 3, 0, 1, 2, 3, 0, 1, 2, 3, 0, 1, 2, 3, 0, 1, 2, 3, 0, 1, 2, 3, 0,
        1, 2, 3], dtype=int32))
```

While `np.nonzero(idx1)` is

```
(array([2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4], dtype=int32),
 array([2, 3, 4, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4], dtype=int32),
 array([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], dtype=int32))
```

With the obvious omission of `Y` it works with your 2d example.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand the question, I think you want to reduce one of the axes in your array using the `or` function, similar to the way you can with the python builtin `reduce`.

Numpy functions have a method like that called `reduce`:

```
idx2 = np.zeros_like(idx)
idx2[:,:,0] = np.logical_or.reduce(idx, axis=2)
```

Here are the results.  I believe the condition that you want this to satisfy is that for any `idx[i][j][k]` that is `True`, `idx2[i][j][0]` also is `True`, and for any other values of `i` and `j`, `idx2[i][j]0]` is `False`.

I believe the following satisfies that.
Here you have idx:

```
array([[[False, False, False, False],
        [False, False, False, False],
        [False, False, False, False],
        [False, False, False, False],
        [False, False, False, False]],

       [[False, False, False, False],
        [False, False, False, False],
        [False, False, False, False],
        [False, False, False, False],
        [False, False, False, False]],

       [[False, False, False, False],
        [False, False, False, False],
        [False, False, False,  True],
        [ True,  True,  True,  True],
        [ True,  True,  True,  True]],

       [[ True,  True,  True,  True],
        [ True,  True,  True,  True],
        [ True,  True,  True,  True],
        [ True,  True,  True,  True],
        [ True,  True,  True,  True]],

       [[ True,  True,  True,  True],
        [ True,  True,  True,  True],
        [ True,  True,  True,  True],
        [ True,  True,  True,  True],
        [ True,  True,  True,  True]]], dtype=bool)
```

And here is idx2:

```
array([[[False, False, False, False],
        [False, False, False, False],
        [False, False, False, False],
        [False, False, False, False],
        [False, False, False, False]],

       [[False, False, False, False],
        [False, False, False, False],
        [False, False, False, False],
        [False, False, False, False],
        [False, False, False, False]],

       [[False, False, False, False],
        [False, False, False, False],
        [ True, False, False, False],
        [ True, False, False, False],
        [ True, False, False, False]],

       [[ True, False, False, False],
        [ True, False, False, False],
        [ True, False, False, False],
        [ True, False, False, False],
        [ True, False, False, False]],

       [[ True, False, False, False],
        [ True, False, False, False],
        [ True, False, False, False],
        [ True, False, False, False],
        [ True, False, False, False]]], dtype=bool)
```

In your simpler, 2d case,

```
test = np.arange(0, 10, 1).reshape((5, -1), order='F')
idx = test > 5

idx2 = np.zeros_like(idx)
idx2[:,0] = np.logical_or.reduce(idx, axis=1)  # Note the reduction in dimension of the slicing, and that axis=1
idx2

array([[False, False],
       [ True, False],
       [ True, False],
       [ True, False],
       [ True, False]], dtype=bool)
```

## General function

If you want a general function, here is one that works for any number of dimensions:

```
def logical_flatten(array_in):
    array_out = np.zeros_like(array_in)
    array_out[[Ellipsis for k in range(len(array_in.shape)-1)]+[0]] = np.logical_or.reduce(array_in, axis=len(array_in.shape)-1)
    return array_out
```

Comment: I think I have it now - see if this is what you want.